# If $u_n \to u$ locally uniformly and $u_n \to w$ weakly-star in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, is it true that $u = w$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $u_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that there exists $u$ such that $u_n \to u$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

- If $u_n \to w$ weakly-star in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, is it true that $u = w$? If in addition we assume that $u_n$ are uniformly bounded,does the result hold?
- If $u_n \to w$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is it true that $u=w$?

Comment: The answer to your second question is of course yes.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp That would be my guess too. But why exactly is that true?

Comment: That is trivial. You have u = w on each compact set. So u = w. But I have a question: Do you assume u and/or $u_n$ to be in $L^\infty$?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Yes, I forgot to write it: $u_n$ are uniformly bounded.

Comment: $u_n \to w$ weakly-star implies  that if you change w on a measure zero set and get $w'$ still you have $u_n \to w'$, (weakly-star) so the answer of first question is No. And in second one both implies pointwise convergence so the answer is yes.

Comment: @Ashkan I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Here is the answer to your first question: u and w are equal almost everywhere. You can easily prove that u = w (a.e.) on compact sets. And of course Ashkan is right.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Thanks. Would you mind writing up a more detailed answer on that?

Comment: Yes, I mind. Go and estimate $\left|\int_K(w-u)v\,dx\right|$, where $v\in L^1$ and $K$ a compact set.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Alright, got it. But what if I added that $w$ is also continuous and bounded?

Comment: You don't need to say that it is bounded. Since it is essentially bounded, if you say it is continuous, then it is bounded. In this case, clearly, $w = u$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Why is it essentially bounded?

Comment: Well, if you say that $u_n\to w$ in the weak* topology of $L^\infty$, then $w$ should be in $L^\infty$, right?